# Stuck on Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: javascript

I'm working through my first JS project and making a basic Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I get stuck when I attempt to play a single round. I don't know if my code accepts case-insensitive input from the user (rock, Rock, ROCK, rOcK).
My console seems to display a random result of the game. For example, if I input Rock, and the computer also inputs Rock, the console sometimes displays "You win!", and I don't know why that's happening.
Here is my code below. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) 
 switch (randomNum) { 
     case 0:
         return "rock";
     case 1:
         return "paper";
     case 2:
         return "scissors";
 }
 }
console.log(getComputerChoice());

function userInput() {
   const ask = prompt("To begin game, select Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
    return ask.toLowerCase();
    
 }

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
         return "You win!";
     } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") {
         return "You lose";
     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
         return "You win!";
     } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock") {
         return "You lose";
     } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
         return "You win!";
     } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
         return "You lose";
     } else if (playerSelection ==  computerSelection) {
         return "It's a tie";
     } else {
         return "Try again";
     }
 }

    const playerSelection = userInput();
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: The computer choice you log vs the computer choice you use are *different*. Calling the function doesn't make it return the same thing.

Comment: It looks like your program works properly, other than displaying a misleading computer choice that isn't used.  You could console.log(playerSelection, computerSelection) after you have assigned them near the bottom, to be doubly sure.

Comment: Other than what @caTS said, the code is all right. I hope you enjoy your learning

Comment: This code would be 10x easier to read if instead of all the `"scissors"` junk and the long variable names you just used short conventions like `R`, `P` and `S`. Consider a guess pair as a short string: `RP` = player (rock), opponent (paper). Then the win/loss tables are super easy, it's just a look-up. Zero `if` statements required, as in `{ RP: 'O', PR: 'P', ... }` As there are only 3*3, or 9 possible outcomes, this table is super small.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are displaying a random computer choice, then selecting again for the game. To fix this remove line 12 (`console.log(getComputerChoice());`) and add the following line right after you declare computerSelection:

```js
console.log(computerSelection);
```

Here is the final code:

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) 
  switch (randomNum) { 
    case 0:
      return "rock";
    case 1:
      return "paper";
    case 2:
      return "scissors";
  }
}

function userInput() {
  const ask = prompt("To begin game, select Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
  return ask.toLowerCase();
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
    return "You win!";
  } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") {
    return "You lose";
  } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
    return "You win!";
  } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock") {
    return "You lose";
  } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
    return "You win!";
  } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
    return "You lose";
  } else if (playerSelection ==  computerSelection) {
    return "It's a tie";
  } else {
    return "Try again";
  }
}

const playerSelection = userInput();
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(computerSelection);
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```